combinations problem - teachers to groups
My question is in how many ways can you divide 20 teachers into two groups, one group would have 15 people and the other would have 5.
I tried Benjamin Dickman's formula but it did not work out =, the right answer is 15504 I don't even know where to start.

Look at the choose function, e.g: https://alexderivesstuff.wordpress.com/2013/02/05/the-choose-function/

Dividing the teachers into two groups can be done in two steps.

Choose any 15 teachers from 20 teachers and make a group.
Make another group of the 5 remaining teachers.

Thus, the number of possible ways = ${20}\choose{15}$${5}\choose{5}$$=15504$.

This was very helpful thank you very much!

This is a bizarre sentence to read!

I tried Benjamin Dickman's formula but it did not work out =, the right answer is 15504 I don't even know where to start.

I will guess that you are referring to my answer from Sep 2013 to MSE 507681 (?).
Using that formula for your problem here, you can line up twenty teachers in $20!$ ways. Put in a divider after the fifteenth teacher; using the A to Z alphabet, this would mean:
$$ABCEDFGHIJKLMNO|PQRST$$
But, the group of fifteen is overcounted by a factor of $15!$ and the group of five is overcounted by a factor of $5!$, which means that we can get a final answer by computing:
$$\frac{20!}{15!5!} = \frac{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17 \cdot 16}{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} = \frac{1860480}{120} = 15504,$$
which is "the right answer" as specified in your post.
That said, the problem you have here is equivalent to asking how many ways you can pick five out of twenty teachers; after all, each of these possibilities yields a group of five and a group of fifteen. In other words, it suffices to compute $C(20,5)$ aka $_{20}C_{5}$, which is equivalent to $20!/(15!5!)$ as written above, and which you could calculate, for example, using WolframAlpha.
